# Does Flume have Excel source

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am just wondering has anybody come across the scenario where you need to import or read the data from excel to Hadoop? Is there such thing like Flume Excel source around?

btw, I know I can convert the excel file to csv then deal with it. Really just trying to explore flume source a bit further here.

Answer (score 2):

[Spooling Directory Source](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source) can be configured to read from Excel files (or any other format). As documentation states, this source can be configured with [EventDeserializer](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=blob;f=flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/serialization/EventDeserializer.java;h=bbb337593eec17644e572ea3f33cb194a37cfe66;hb=HEAD) - the class that implements logic of parsing the file into events.

I don't think somebody already implemented such deserializer, but it seems to be quite easy task with Apache POI library.